# Issue using MapContainer from react-leaflet: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geolocation, openstreetmap, react-leaflet

I'm trying to use React Leaflet to add a map from OpenStreetMap on my website. Everything seems to go well syntax wise, however when I try to use  I encounter this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
> at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
> at MapContainerComponent (MapContainer.js:19:1)
> and

> react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(MapContainerComponent)> component: at MapContainerComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:134734:3)

> react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Not sure where I should start looking to fix the errors. Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker } from 'react-leaflet';
import osm from './Leaflet/osmprovider';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import '../App.css';

const SOCIAL_LINKS = [
    {   
        name: "Facebook",
        link: "https://www.facebook.com/TESOLintl",
        icon: "facebook-f",
    },
];

function Footer() {
    const ZOOM_LEVEL = 13;
    const center = {
        lat: 14.9221,
        lng: 120.8448
    };
    
    return (
        <div className='Footer'>
            <div className="row">
                
                <div className="col OSM">
                    <MapContainer
                        center={center}
                        zoom={ZOOM_LEVEL}
                        scrollWheelZoom={false}
                    >
                        <TileLayer url={osm.maptiler.url} attribution={osm.maptiler.attribution} />
                        <Marker position={center}></Marker>
                    </MapContainer>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
        
        </div>
    );
    
}
```

I'm using react v 18.2.0, react-leaflet is v 4.2.1 and I use webpack v 5.0.1

Uninstalling and Re-installing doesn't work as well